# Python, sqlite3 syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Сделал простую программу, но не могу понять почему один раз из пяти все работает и в базу добавляются данные, а остальные четыре ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\engdict.py", line 27, in <module>
    addInDB()
  File "D:\python\engdict.py", line 24, in addInDB
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO All_Words VALUES (NULL, '{word}', '{short}', '{long_}')")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error
```

Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3

def getWord():
    url = 'https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/randomword'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    h1 = soup.find('h1', class_='dynamictext').text
    shortMeaning = soup.find('p', class_='short').text
    longMeaning = soup.find('p', class_='long').text
    full = [h1, shortMeaning, longMeaning]
    return full

def addInDB():
    full = getWord()
    word = full[0].capitalize()
    short = full[1]
    long_ = full[2]
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO All_Words VALUES (NULL, '{word}', '{short}', '{long_}')")
    conn.commit()

addInDB()
```

Upd: Проблема была в форматировании строк, ниже - код, который работает нормально.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3
import json


def getWord():
    url = 'https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/randomword'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    h1 = soup.find('h1', class_='dynamictext').text
    shortMeaning = soup.find('p', class_='short').text
    longMeaning = soup.find('p', class_='long').text
    full = [h1, shortMeaning, longMeaning]
    return full

def addInDB():
    full = getWord()
    print(full)
    word = full[0].capitalize()
    short = json.dumps([full[1]])
    long_ = json.dumps([full[2]])
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO All_Words VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)", [word, short, long_])
    conn.commit()

addInDB()
```

Comment: «...один раз из пяти все работает и в базу добавляются данные, а остальные **пять** ошибка: » - `5 - 1 = 5`??

Comment: Попробуйте `print(full)` после `full = getWord()`, чтобы увидеть, что будет записываться в ДБ.

Comment: @MarianD Спасибо, понял свою ошибку.

Comment: @KOTIK, не стоит.